# pm2 watching inside folders, having issues

Tags: javascript, discord, pm2, discord.js

I'm trying to have pm2 watch everything in events, commands, data, index.js, and config.js.

pm2 --name druggy --watch 
events,commands,data,index.js,config.js/index.js start node -- index.js

I used this and whenever I try to change a file in one of the folders, when I save my bot it doesn't restart. However it does restart if I change the index.js. How can I make it restart when I change anything inside those folders and the two files?

Answer (score 0):

Do not give `--watch` any parameters. You do not pass them in through the command line, anyways. Change your command to the following:

`pm2 start index.js --name druggy --watch`

If you do want to specify which paths to `watch`, then follow the documentation located [here](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/).